# Do King and Diane have any kids?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the last Nanatsu no Taizai movie, and in the last Nanatsu no Taizai series, we see Meliodas and Ban have children. How about King and Diane? Do they have any, and if so, where are they, why don't we see them?